# Showing $\frac{|\vec{A_1B}|}{|\vec{A_1C}|}\frac{|\vec{B_1C}|}{|\vec{B_1A}|}\frac{|\vec{C_1A}|}{|\vec{C_1B}|}=1$ implies $AA_1$, $BB_1$, $CC_1$ concur

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

Hello I am trying too hard but still can't solve this

> Let's assume a random triangle $\triangle  ABC$ and points $A_1$, $B_1$, $C_1$ on edges $BC$, $AC$, $BA$, respectively.
> Known that:
> $$ \frac{|\overrightarrow{A_1B}|} {|\overrightarrow{A_1C}|}  \frac{|\overrightarrow{B_1C}|} {|\overrightarrow{B_1A}|}  \frac{|\overrightarrow{C_1A}|} {|\overrightarrow{C_1B}|} =1 $$
> Show with **vector analysis** that $\overleftrightarrow{AA_1}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BB_1}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CC_1}$ are concurrent lines.

First of all I draw the problem information in paper as shown in **Figure 1** and I think my goal is to show that $$|{\overrightarrow{AA_1}}\, {\overrightarrow{BB_1}}\,{\overrightarrow{CC_1}}| = 0$$

[image]

I use a theorem shown in **Figure 2**.

> If
> $$ \frac{\overrightarrow{AM}} {\overrightarrow{MB}} =k$$
> then
> $$\overrightarrow{OM}=\frac{\overrightarrow{OA}+k \overrightarrow{OB}}{1+k}$$

[image]

let's say that
$$ k_a=\frac{\mathop {CA_1}\limits^ \to } { \mathop {A_1B}\limits^ \to},k_b=\frac{\mathop {AB_1}\limits^ \to } { \mathop {B_1C}\limits^ \to} , k_c=\frac{\mathop {BC_1}\limits^ \to } { \mathop {C_1A}\limits^ \to}$$
then I get
$$ \mathop {AA_1}\limits^ \to=\frac{\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to +k_a \mathop {AC}\limits^ \to} {1+k_a},\mathop {BB_1}\limits^ \to=\frac{\mathop {BA}\limits^ \to +k_b \mathop {BC}\limits^ \to} {1+k_b},\mathop {CC_1}\limits^ \to=\frac{\mathop {CB}\limits^ \to +k_c \mathop {CA}\limits^ \to} {1+k_c} $$

by multiplication I get
$$ \mathop {AA_1}\limits^ \to \mathop {BB_1}\limits^ \to \mathop {CC_1}\limits^ \to =\frac{(\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to +k_a \mathop {AC}\limits^ \to)(\mathop {BA}\limits^ \to +k_b \mathop {BC}\limits^ \to)(\mathop {CB}\limits^ \to +k_c \mathop {CA}\limits^ \to)} {(1+k_a)(1+k_b)(1+k_c)} $$

I think almost there because denominator is positive because k are positives so
numerator should be zero to achieve my goal.After numerator multiplication I get
$\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to \mathop {BA}\limits^ \to \mathop {CA}\limits^ \to k_a k_c $
$+\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to \mathop {BA}\limits^ \to \mathop {CB}\limits^ \to k_a $
$+\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to \mathop {BC}\limits^ \to \mathop {CA}\limits^ \to k_a k_b k_c $
$+\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to \mathop {BC}\limits^ \to \mathop {CB}\limits^ \to k_a k_b $
$+\mathop {AC}\limits^ \to \mathop {BA}\limits^ \to \mathop {CA}\limits^ \to k_c $
$+\mathop {AC}\limits^ \to \mathop {BA}\limits^ \to \mathop {CB}\limits^ \to $
$+\mathop {AC}\limits^ \to \mathop {BC}\limits^ \to \mathop {CA}\limits^ \to k_b k_c $
$+\mathop {AC}\limits^ \to \mathop {BC}\limits^ \to \mathop {CB}\limits^ \to k_b $

now I can't do much.
Only because $k_ak_bk_c=1$ I get

$\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to \mathop {BA}\limits^ \to \mathop {CA}\limits^ \to k_a k_c $
$+\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to \mathop {BA}\limits^ \to \mathop {CB}\limits^ \to k_a $
$+\mathop {AB}\limits^ \to \mathop {BC}\limits^ \to \mathop {CB}\limits^ \to k_a k_b $
$+\mathop {AC}\limits^ \to \mathop {BA}\limits^ \to \mathop {CA}\limits^ \to k_c $
$+\mathop {AC}\limits^ \to \mathop {BC}\limits^ \to \mathop {CA}\limits^ \to k_b k_c $
$+\mathop {AC}\limits^ \to \mathop {BC}\limits^ \to \mathop {CB}\limits^ \to k_b $

after that I can't see any continuation. Can you help me? If there is more efficient way I am happy to know. Thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of the Ceva's theorem?

Comment: No really. But If It's help I'll google it.

Comment: Don't format a vector $\mathop {XY}\limits^ \to$ using `$\mathop {XY}\limits^ \to$`. Instead, write $\vec{XY}$ using `$\vec{XY}$` or $\overrightarrow{XY}$ using `$\overrightarrrow{XY}$`. (I prefer the latter, as the arrow goes all the way across.) I started making the changes for you, but there are just *so many* instances. :)

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it's look better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let ABC be a triangle and suppose that P divides BC in the ratio 1 : s
> and that Q divides CA in the ratio 1 : t and that R divides AB in the
> ratio 1 : u. Then AP, BQ and CR are concurrent if and only if stu = 1.

**PROOF**

[image]

We can write the line through the points A and P in a parametric form with parameter alpha:

[image]

Similarly, we can write the line through the points B and Q in a parametric form with parameter beta:

[image]

Since the expressions are in the triangle coordinate form -

[image]

their coefficients will be equal at their point of intersection, thus we can equate coefficients of A and B, then solve for aplha and beta:

[image]

[image]

Solving for alpha

[image]

[image]

[image]

Similarly we work out coefficients of B and C to get:

[image] .....[10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdSb5.png)

Now we can avoid doing whole procedure again by cyclically permuting all the quantities involved. Hence we get:

[image] .....[11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXbbP.png)

Expressions [10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdSb5.png), [11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXbbP.png) are equal if and only if stu=1.

Hence proven

Comment: Thank you! It's help a lot!

Comment: This is an important result and can prove to be useful in many problems. I suggest you to Google Ceva's Theorem and its counterpart, Menelau's theorem